# How to upload a zip file using javascript language?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

So, I am trying to upload a zip file into a directory(i.e. project directory) for that I am using `vuejs` to upload the file. Once the file gets selected I am able to convert it into `base64` string by using `FileReader`, but stuck on how to write that base64 string to a zip file and uncompressed that file in a directory.

File upload code:

```
<v-file-input
 v-model="zipFile"
 accept=".zip"
 placeholder="Pick a zip file"
 prepend-icon="mdi-file"
 label="zip file"
 class="ml-2"
 outlined
 @change="uploadZip"
 ></v-file-input>
```

Js code:

```
uploadZip() {
      let file = this.zipFile;
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onload = (evt) => {
        console.log(evt.target.result); //base64 string
        // Got confused how to write into zip file and then uncompressed it
      };
      reader.onerror = (evt) => {
        console.error(evt);
      };
    },
```

Any clue that helps me to accomplish the solution?

Comment: i believe FormData wil get you a end.   `let formdata = new FormData(); zip_data = reader.readAsBinaryString(file);  FormData.append('zip_data', zip_data);`   then use ajax to send it JQuery is more easy as you can do `$ajax { .... formdata: formdata  .... }`  p.s non tested might not work al besides that i didnt do javascript in a while

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I do that if I wanted to save it in that project directory? I don't want to call an API to store it somewhere else.

Comment: You have to have a backend server to process the request and to handle the uploaded file request.